# Imaginary part of permittivity tensor

Tags: electromagnetism, dielectric, optical-materials

For a general permittivity tensor, why is the imaginary part of the off-diagonal component, e.g.:

$$\epsilon_{xy}$$

equal to:

$$\frac{\epsilon_{xy} + \epsilon_{yx}^*}{2i}$$

instead of:

$$(\epsilon_{xy} + \epsilon_{xy}^*)/2i$$

Comment: Where did you get this relation?

Comment: Because when you take complex conjugate of a matrix in addition of conjugating elements you must replace index of column with index of row I.e. $[\epsilon_{xy}]^\dagger=[\epsilon^*_{yx}]$

Comment: I don't understand why we need to take the Hermitian conjugate of the epsilon tensor though? Could you explain the intuition behind this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can split the permittivity $\epsilon$ into to part 1) refractive part $\epsilon_r$ and 2) absorptive part $\epsilon_a$ as follows:
$$\epsilon = \epsilon_r + i\epsilon_a     (1)$$
permittivity tensors $\epsilon_r$ and $\epsilon_a$ must be hermitian because both are physical quantities i.e.
$$\epsilon_r^\dagger = \epsilon_r     (2)$$
$$\epsilon_a^\dagger = \epsilon_a     (3)$$
Therefore getting hermittian conjugate of equation (1) we have
$$\epsilon^\dagger = \epsilon_r - i\epsilon_a     (4)$$
Adding and subtracting (1) and (4) get
$$\epsilon_r  = \frac{\epsilon +\epsilon^\dagger}{2}     (5)$$
$$\epsilon_r  = \frac{\epsilon -\epsilon^\dagger}{2i}     (6)$$

Be ware when you take complex conjugate of a matrix in addition of conjugating elements you must replace index of column with index of row i.e. $$[\epsilon_{xy}]^†=[\epsilon^*_{yx}]$$